# Name spaces for package name

Tags: java, spring, package

How to write package name more shortly. Is in java or spring some namespaces for package name to make this code more readability.

```
private final static com.training.test.very_long_name.bad_readability._void.ObjectFactory voidFactory = 
new com.training.test.very_long_name.bad_readability._void.ObjectFactory();

private final static com.working.production.very_long_package_name.bad_readability._void.ObjectFactory cgblVoidFactory = 
new com.working.production.very_long_package_name.bad_readability._void.ObjectFactory();
```

Comment: uhhh, import the package?

Comment: Use `import` at the beginning of the file. `import com.training.test.very_long_name.bad_readability._void.ObjectFactory;` and you can do `ObjectFactory voidFactory = new ObjectFactory();`

Comment: @James_Parsons I cant because have two classes with the same name and different packages or I can only for one.

Comment: Seems like you use JAXB schema-derived classes. Why do you need these `ObjectFactory` instances anyway? They don't really have to be used in client code in JAXB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments it seems like you import two (or more) classes with the same local name (`ObjectFactory`).

So the answer is - you can't. If you import `N` classes with the same local name, in `N-1` cases you will need to address them using fully qualified names.